# Why does Ubuntu create multiple instances of the same service having a different pid?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Displaying my services with top on ubuntu, I can see that many services appear multiple times. They have different PIDs and mostly same ressource allocation.

But is this "normal"/intended?

Comment: Depends on the service. Some spawns several processes, some don't.

Comment: For example mysql. Top shows me around 25 instances of /usr/sbin/mysqld or kodi standalone /usr/lob/kodi/kodi.bin --standalone with way more than 40 instances. I wonder if I do something wrong or simply the OS itself is handling them.